# Why is my python function isn't printing even or odd?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

'''def even_or_no(number):
if number % 2 != 0:
return 'odd'
else:
return 'even'

even_or_no(34)'''

Hello, I am trying to print even given that the argument is 34, but it doesn't do that. When I use print statement it works fine. I don't know why my program doesn't return even or odd and prints it onto the screen.

Comment: `When I use print statement it works fine.` Then use it. `I don't know why my program doesn't return even or odd and prints it onto the screen.` Because you're __not__ using print.

Comment: But I don't know why return doesn't work. Is there a problem?

Comment: There is no problem. Return __does not print__, `print` does.

Comment: You seem confused, but I think if you just continue with your tutorial, it's going to come together. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Alright thank you guys, I got it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` simply sends the result of calling your `even_or_no` function back to wherever the function was called. It does **not** print the result unless you explicitly tell it to, such as by calling `print(even_or_no(34))`.

You can read more about `return` statements in Python [here](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got it now :)

Comment: @Eve Glad to hear it! If my answer helped, please check the green check mark to the left to confirm it as the answer in case future readers have the same question